# How can I use variables from a form globally in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-8

I want to use a variables from a form globally but I don't know how do it with Laravel 8

[image]
For example, I want to write in "Alfabeto" a string like this: "a, b, c, d" and that when pressing "Confirmar" I can use this variable with the string "a, b, c, d" in any of the blade views.

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 2%;">
<label for="alfabetoAutomata">Alfabeto</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="alfabetoAutomata" id="alfabetoAutomata" title="Debe ingresar el alfabeto como el siguiente ejemplo: a,b,c" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(,[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$" placeholder="Ingrese el alfabeto para los autómatas separados por comas. (Ej: a,b,c)" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['alfabetoAutomata'] ?? '', ENT_QUOTES); ?>" required>
</div>
```

I want to use the var `$_GET['alfabetoAutomata']` globally, how I can do it?

I hope I have made myself understood, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the View::share documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views
If that is not what you are looking for, then I would suggest, inside your controller, set a session variable like this.

```
 Session::put('foo', 'bar')
```

Above foo is the name of the variable and bar is the value. Now, when I need to change the value of foo, for example in a blade file,  I can do so like this.

```
{{Session::put('foo','Another Bar')}}
```